# Unable to use variable count in terragrunt

Tags: terragrunt

First I created a lifecycle policy using terraform uisng this link https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dlm_lifecycle_policy . Later I used terragrunt to create the lifecycle policy but I get error using the variable count.I declared the variable as a number datatype.
I get this error while running terragrunt plan-all
'''
Error: Invalid variable name

on variables.tf line 36, in variable "count":
36: variable "count"{

The variable name "count" is reserved due to its special meaning inside module
blocks.
'''

[terragrunt] 2021/01/26 20:51:01 Encountered the following errors:
Hit multiple errors:
exit status 1

How can I fix this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do about it, as error shows terraform has some variable names reserved for internal use,

https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#declaring-an-input-variable

only thing you can do is to choose another name for your variable.